# Event horizon in stationary spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, event-horizon

In the case of non-stationary spacetimes finding the event horizon is no easy task.
The stationary case should somehow be less involved or so it is in some well known cases, such as the Kerr spacetime.
I find (apparently) conflicting information about the way one finds the event horizon in such cases and I want to understand which of two conditions is more appropriate. Unfortunately, they seem to be equivalent in the case of the Kerr metric. I wonder if that's the case for non-Kerr stationary spacetimes.
Let me sketch the two alternatives:

1. On the one hand, Ref.1 uses the fact that in stationary spacetimes the event horizon is an apparent horizon and thus a *stationary null hypersurface* (this time stationary meaning that the Raychaudhauri expansion is zero $\Theta=0$). Then using the fact that

> the normal to any stationary hypersurface must be proportional to $\partial_\alpha r$
> (I'd be grateful if you also pointed out why. Here $r$ is a Boyer-Lindquist coordinate), then the null condition obviously boils down to the inverse metric satisfying $g^{rr}=0$.

2. My notes define the EH instead as the hypersurface defined by the ZAMO limit, namely $(g^{tt})^{-1}=0\iff \frac{g_{tt}g_{\varphi\varphi}-g_{t\varphi}^2}{g_{\varphi\varphi}}=0$.

I should also say that all this assumes a metric of the form
$$ds^2=-|g_{tt}|dt^2+g_{rr}dr^2+g_{\theta\theta}d\theta^2+g_{\varphi\varphi}d\varphi^2+2g_{t\varphi}dtd\varphi.$$

Which of the two conditions is correct and why?

---

#### References

1. A Relativist's Toolkit: The Mathematics of Black-Hole Mechanics, Eric Poisson. CUP, 2004. Section 5.3.4 (Last paragraph of page 190)

Comment: Did you see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277720

Comment: As I write at the beginning, I know that for non-stationary spacetimes it is more involved. The case of stationary spacetimes has some shortcuts though, as I mentioned for the cases of the Kerr BH. My question is about the meaning of two different conditions, which is not addressed (or at least not so explicitly that I can see it) in that answer, which I'd already seen by the way.

Comment: Based on the answer in the mentioned stack exchange link the entire notion of event horizons seems rather questionable in the case of non-stationary spacetimes. We find this situation in physics quite often. Electrostatic potentials don't exist for non-stationary electromagnetic fields, for instance. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: Once again, I'm not concerned with non-stationary spacetimes, but with *stationary* ones.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question based on your first sentence. Apologies.

Comment: @FlatterMann No worries. :)

Comment: The way you find the event horizon has a very specific method, which I think was cleared in a work on Cartan invariants in the Newman-Penrose formalism with the zeroes of invariants like $\Delta \rho /\rho $. But I am not sure if it is the most general way of horizon detection. The horizon is something that in general needs full data for the spacetime. But this is out of my expertise.

Answer (score 0):

The two conditions are equivalent, see Eq. (5.46) of your Ref. 1:
$$g^{tt} = - \frac{\Sigma}{\rho^2 \Delta}, \quad  g^{rr} = \frac{\Delta}{\rho^2} \; .$$
Since $(g^{tt})^{-1} = - \frac{\rho^2 \Delta}{\Sigma}$ and $\rho^2=0$ corresponds to a true physical singularity (as opposed to the coordinate singularity at $\Delta =0$), either one of $(g^{tt})^{-1} = 0$ or $g^{rr}=0$ implies the other.

For metric-independent definitions of the apparent and event horizon see Appendix A.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.06515 (and references therein).

Comment: I know that they are equivalent for the Kerr metric, as I said at the beginning of my post. The two definitions arise independently of Kerr, though. I'm asking whether if they're still equivalent for a generic stationary spacetime. For a general stationary metric, it doesn't seem to me that $(g^{tt})^{-1}=0\iff \frac{g_{tt}g_{\varphi\varphi}-g_{t\varphi}^2}{g_{\varphi\varphi}}=0$ and $g^{rr}=0$ are the same condition, then which one is the proper condition?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean when you write "generic stationary spacetime". It certainly holds for the metric that you have specified above. If you don't know the metric you'll have to resort to geometric/topological definitions as I mentioned in my response.

Comment: The Kerr metric is a *special* case of the metric I've written (at least in principle). A spacetime is stationary if there exists an asymptotic timelike Killing vector field (in other words, the metric components are time independent choosing appropriate coordinates). I didn't say the metric is unknown, rather that it doesn't have to be *Kerr* (as in your equations), for which there was no doubt in the first place.

Comment: Sure, but without knowing any of the relations for the components of your metric (e.g. those akin to Kerr) it is impossible to determine what condition would correspond to the location of the event horizon (if the metric even has one).

Comment: The way both my sources work is not specific to the Kerr metric, but to stationary axisymmetric spacetimes only. They are not observing "hey, look: the event horizon happens to satisfy this equation in the Kerr case". Rather they argue that such a condition would locate an apparent horizon (which in a stationary spacetime will be the even horizon). There is nothing specific to this case in how things are being formulated.

Comment: The Kerr metric is the only explicitly known exact solution that describes axially symmetric black hole spacetimes. So sure, you can claim that your metric can be used to describe generic axially symmetric spacetimes, but they won't have an event horizon unless they are related to the Kerr metric. Hope this helps.